# JSF Seam StatusMessages read from Java

Tags: jsf, seam

i have a JSF/Seam Page and added a new not HTML Interface. I reused the business logic, so StatusMessages.instance().add is used everywhere.

Is there a default way to access and handle this StatusMessages from Java or do i have to extend the base class and pass the protected messages list?

thx

Edit:

```
StatusMessages.instance().add(Severity.ERROR, "Please enter a username.");
```

The FacesMessages is not returning his own messages List (where i saw the entry in the debugger) (FacesMessages.instance() is the same object as StatusMessages.instance() )

```
FacesMessages.instance().getCurrentMessages();
```

It is calling this

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getMessages();
```

and this is returning an empty iterator.

Comment: my bad, google didn't helped, but a look in the type hierarchy helped to find the class FacesMessages.

Comment: ok FacesMessages the field messages contains the 2 messages i added, but when i try to access them FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getMessages() is called and no messages are returned.

Comment: Code of what? I do the two statements above. I post one statusmessage and then i want to read all of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`StatusMessages` is abstraction for handing messages in a way that is not dependent on the view technology you are using.

Default implementation of this abstraction is `org.jboss.seam.faces.FacesMessages`. This is included in Seam for use with JSF.

If are reusing you business logic with another view technology you could provide your specific `StatusMessages` implementation. Actually, that's why this is an abstraction.

```
@Scope(ScopeType.CONVERSATION)
@Name(StatusMessages.COMPONENT_NAME)
@Install(precedence=APPLICATION)
@BypassInterceptors
public class NonHtmlMessages extends StatusMessages
{
  /// implement here you message handling
```

Because of `@Install` precedence this will automatically be used in all `StatusMessages.instance()`.

Comment: I used reflection to access the protected method "getMessages()". In your example i had to remove (precedence=APPLICATION) because he wouldn't find it, but it is the default anyway. And i extended FacesMessages and just added the getMessages() as a public method. works too and i can at least skip the reflection now. But would have been interessting anyway why FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getMessages() returns an empty iterator, if you know.

Comment: I have no idea on why you find that iterator empty, sorry. Once I tried to manipulate FacesMessages inside FacesContext on WebSphere but I soon gave up. I think the way it works deeply depends on the JSF implementation.